# Submitting variable number of arrays to underscore _.difference

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a variable number of arrays I would like to submit to [underscore.js `_.difference`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference). How can I submit them to this function?

```
var arrays = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,3,6]];
var result = _.difference.apply(null, arrays);
```

seems to work. But I'm not sure if this is how `apply()` is meant to be used. Is there a better method?

Comment: @Pavlo an array of arrays. Edited

Comment: What are you trying to compare `arrays` to?

Comment: That is in fact for what apply is used.  http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Apply_Functional_Programming_Principles

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine, but I would change the context to Underscore object itself:

```
var result = _.difference.apply(_, arrays);
```

It will work the same, because [`this` keyword is not used inside the method](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L506), but it's a good practice to keep the context.

---

E. g. when you use `this` in your own mixin, not keeping the context will break it:

```
_.mixin({
  getVersion: function() {
    return this.VERSION;
  }
});

_.getVersion();               // '1.4.4'
_.getVersion.apply(null, []); // undefined
_.getVersion.apply(_, []);    // '1.4.4'
```

Comment: Would this ever make any kind of difference?

Comment: Yes, if `this` keyword is used inside the method. [In our case it isn't](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L506), but it's a good practice to keep the context.

Comment: Why is it good practice? Can you show an example of how it would be useful? Thanks!